# socket.io - stop receiving own emits

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

TL;DR - How to prevent client from receiving its own messages?

So I'm playing with socket.io after my experience with `apollo` and `graphql`.

My simple server looks like this:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('New connection established.');
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('User disconnected.');
  });
  // Projects:
  socket.on('join project', (data) => {
    console.log(`User (${data.user.email}) join project with ID ${data.project.id}`);
    socket.join(data.project.id);
  });
  socket.on('leave project', (data) => {
    socket.leave(data.project.id);
  });

  socket.on('change field', (data) => {
    console.log('Field was changed:', data);
    const { project } = data;
    socket.to(project.id).broadcast.emit('field changed', data);
  });
});
```

I'm emitting something like this inside my application:

```
socket.emit('change field', {
          project: {
            id: 1,
          },
          value: 'Hello world',
          usersEmail: 'example@email.com',
          fieldName: 'description',
        });
socket.on('field changed', (data) => {
      // if (data.usersEmail === 'example@email.com') return; // This would stop from receiving own messages
      console.log('CLIENT: field was changed!', data);
    });
```

What I thought would happen is (due to the `broadcast` flag that I set up in the `on('change field', ...)`):

1. Clients A emits the message
2. Clients other than A receive the message

What is happening is a log inside other clients and client A itself, saying that the field was changed. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. Couldn't (or didn't try hard enough) to find a setting for it, so instead just added this to my clients on page load:

```
document.windowid = Math.round(Math.random() * 1000000000000);
```

Then, add this to the message you emit in your client:

```
windowid: document.windowid
```

Then, when you accept data on the client, only do the action when windowid is not the same:

```
if (message.windowid != document.windowid)
```

It's not great and socket.io should take care of this issue, but this is the solution I used in my app :)

Comment: Mine problem was not related to socket.io at all. I was trying to use it inside my react project with `recompose` package. Passing socket instance to `withProps` method of `recompose` caused this. Thank anyway!